# Как запускать скрипты из других скриптов?

Tags: python

Пишу бота для телеграмма. Появилась такая надобность, как запускать бота, так и его выключать. То есть, пишу /start - запускается, /stop - останавливается. И возникла такая идея. Будет всего 2 скрипта, один будет принимать команды и разные сообщения,  а второй скрипт будет запускаться в зависимости от пришедшей команды. То есть, в боте пишу /start, первый скрипт слушает это - получает команду /start, затем еще пару сообщений и запускается второй скрипт. Затем если нужно его остановить то пишу /stop, первый скрипт получает эту команду и останавливает второй скрипт. Может идея бред, но как такое реализовать? Как запускать скрипты из других файлов(скриптов)? В python

Comment: а чего 2й скрипт делает ? пусть бот сам делает всё

Comment: второй скрипт открывает сессию для парсинга постов из телеграмм каналов. В нем используется библиотека `telethon`. И еще нужно передать из первого скрипта во второй параметры. Можно ли так сделать?

Comment: У меня не получается останавливать скрипт. Поэтому пришла такая идея разделить это все

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import  subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['python', 'script.py', 'arg1'])
```

Или

```
import sys,  subprocess
subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'script.py', 'arg1'])
```

Или (если запускаемый файл это набор функций, возможно так и остальной код выполняется при импорте, но не проверял)

```
import script #Файл script.py должен лежать рядом с запускаемым файлом
script.botStart('arg1')
```

Comment: То есть этот код `import  subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['python', 'script.py', 'arg1'])` должен быть в первом скрипте, да? А как принимать аргументы во втором файле?

Comment: Да, аргументы принимать так `sys.argv[2]...`

Comment: Ага, ок, понял. А при отправки команды /stop, как останавливать этот файл? Popen.kill()?

Comment: А вот с остановкой из другого скрипта даже не знаю, если просто себя нужно остановить, то exit()